# Not getting the expected output from the model query. What query should I use?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, codeigniter-3

I am using Codeigniter,

I have a table and I am inserting the data into the database and data are inserting two times depends on the year and six months.

So my table data is

```
------------------------------------------------
id |m_id  | primary | secondary  | Duration
------------------------------------------------
1  |  1   | 100     | 80         | 12m
------------------------------------------------
2  |  1   | 50      | 40         | 6m
------------------------------------------------
3  |  2   | 300     | 150        | 12m
------------------------------------------------
4  |  2   | 150     | 70         | 6m
------------------------------------------------
5  |  3   | 500     | 300         | 12m
------------------------------------------------
6  |  3   | 300      | 200         | 6m
```

Now I have to fetch data from the database and  I want my output looks like this

```
--------------------------------------------
id  |m_id | primary        | secondary    
    |     | 12m |6m        |12m   |6m        
--------------------------------------------
1   |1    |100  |50        | 80  |40  
--------------------------------------------
2   |2    |300  |150       | 150  |70 
--------------------------------------------
3   |3    |500  |300       | 300  |200
```

So I tried to display the array on the view page so I `print_r($row)` and I am getting the output like

```
stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [m_id] => 1 [primary] => 100 [secondary] =>80 [Duration] => 12m ) 
stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [m_id] => 1 [primary] => 50  [secondary] => 40 [Duration] => 6m) 
stdClass Object ( [id] => 3 [m_id] => 2 [primary] => 300 [secondary] => 150 [Duration] => 12m)
stdClass Object ( [id] => 4 [m_id] => 2 [primary] => 150 [secondary] => 70 [Duration] => 6m)
stdClass Object ( [id] => 5 [m_id] => 3 [primary] => 500 [secondary] => 300 [Duration] => 12m)
stdClass Object ( [id] => 6 [m_id] => 3 [primary] => 300 [secondary] => 200 [Duration] => 6m  )
```

but in the list, I am getting output. I haven't added amount because I am getting the wrong amount. This is not an excepted output.
 There is some issue in my model query.

```
--------------------------------------------
id  |m_id | primary        | secondary    
    |     |12m  |6m        |12m   |6m 
--------------------------------------------
 1  |1    |     |          |      | 
 2  |1    |     |          |      | 
 3  |2    |     |          |      | 
 4  |2    |     |          |      |
 5  |3    |     |          |      | 
 6  |3    |     |          |      |
```

My view code is

```
<table id="list" border="1">
        <thead>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">id</th>
    <th rowspan="2">m_id</th>
    <th colspan="2">Primary</th>
    <th colspan="2">Secondary</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>12m</th>
    <th>6m</th>
    <th>12m</th>
    <th>6m</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
        <tbody> 

        <?php 

        if($activityfeeslist)
        {
            $n = 1;
            foreach ($activityfeeslist as $rows)
            //print_r($rows);
            if($rows->Duration=='12m'){
                $primary12=$rows->primary;
                $secDep12=$rows->secondary;

            }else{
                $primary6=$rows->primary;
                $secDep6=$rows->secondary;
            }
            {?>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $n++;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $rows->m_id;?></td>

                <td><?php echo $primary12;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $primary6;?></td>

                <td><?php echo $secDep12;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $secDep6;?></td>

        <?php 
        }}?>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

**Controller**

```
public function activityFees()
  {
        $data['activityfeeslist'] = $this->Fees_model->activityFessList();
        $this->load->view('fees/activityFees',$data);
  }
```

**Model**

```
public function activityFessList(){
        $getDetails = array('tbl_activityFees2.is_feesActive'=>1);
        $result = $this->db->where($getDetails)
                           ->select("*")
                           ->from('tbl_activityFees2') 
        ->join('activity_name','activity_name.m_id=tbl_activityFees2.m_id')
                              ->get()
                              ->result();
    if($result)
        {
           return $result;  
        }
        else 
        {
           return 0;    
        }
        }
```

Would you help me out with this issue?

Comment: **tbl_activityFees2.is_feesActive** may be causing your query to return less than expected

Comment: @user2182349, my all the records are active till now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an error in your Model query as in your View.
In view you are iterating and saperating 12m and 6m, instead of doing it in your view you should use a query something like below:

```
$getDetails = array('tbl_activityFees2.is_feesActive'=>1);
$result = $this->db->where($getDetails)
                   ->where('Duration', '=', '12m')
                   ->select('m_id', 'primary as primary12m', 'secondary as secondary12m')
                   ->from('tbl_activityFees2') 
        ->join('tbl_activityFees2 as t2','t2.m_id=tbl_activityFees2.m_id')->where('Duration', '=', '6m')->select('primary as primary6m', 'secondary as secondary6m')
        ->join('activity_name','activity_name.activity_name_id=tbl_activityFees2.activity_name_id')
                      ->get()
                      ->result();
```

I have joined same table two times to get the result directly from query.
Systax me be little bit wrong but I hope you got the idea.

Comment: give me some time to check

Comment: Is it correct where clause   ->where('Duration', '=', 12m)? because I am getting error

Comment: @user9437856 I have updted my post. I have added inverted commas to 12m ->where('Duration', '=', '12m')

Comment: Give me some time to check again

Comment: I have one question about your query. Why we are adding tbl_activityFees2 twice in the query? I mean in the query from tbl_activityFees2 and join tbl_activityFees2?

Comment: Yes, please remove if condition in view. It's no longer required, after the join in SQL.

Comment: We have added activitFee2 twice in SQL in order select the 12m and 6m durations together in a single row. We have applied a join on m_id so that we can have 12m and 6m durations conrresponding to same m_id in same row

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186286/discussion-between-user9437856-and-piyush-aggarwal).

Comment: I found the query but how do I convert it on CodeIgniter? t1`.id
,grouped_data.*
from(
SELECT `t1`.m_id
,max(case when `t1`.duration='12m' then primary end) as primary_12m
,max(case when `t1`.duration='6m' then primary end) as primary_6m
,max(case when `t1`.duration='12m' then secondary end) as secondary_12m
,max(case when `t1`.duration='6m' then secondary end) as secondary_6m
FROM `tbl_activityFees2` as `t1`
WHERE `t1`.`is_feesActive` = 1
GROUP BY `t1`.m_id
) grouped_data
JOIN `tbl_activityFees2` as `t1`
on t1.m_id=grouped_data.m_id

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting rows in your loop at view... than just change the view

Your activityFees controller is correct .. if you have loaded model from constructor else

```
public function activityFees()
  {
        $this->load->model('Fees_model');
        $data['activityfeeslist'] = $this->Fees_model->activityFessList();
        $this->load->view('fees/activityFees',$data);
  }
```

at model you dont have to go as per standard .. so write it as 
and mention join also...

```
    public function activityFessList(){
            $getDetails = array('tbl_activityFees2.is_feesActive'=>1);
            $result = $this->db->select("*")
                               ->from('tbl_activityFees2')
    ->where($getDetails)
->join('activity_name','activity_name.activity_name_id=tbl_activityFees2.activity_name_id','left')
                                  ->get()
                                  ->result();
        if($result)
            {
               return $result;  
            }
            else 
            {
               return 0;    
            }
            }
```

at view

your condition is creating mistake.. . instead of writing condition ... write it as ..

```
<?php  if($activityfeeslist)
        {
            $n = 1;
            foreach ($activityfeeslist as $rows) { ?>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $n++;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $rows->m_id;?></td>

                <td><?php echo $rows->Duration;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $rows->primary;?></td>

                <td><?php echo $rows->Duration;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $rows->secondary;?></td>
             </tr>
        <?php } } ?>
```

Comment: Give me some time to check your answer

Comment: I checked your code. In the view, How can I display my expected output ?

Comment: try $this->db->select("m_id , sum('Duration') as Duration,sum('primary') as primary,sum('secondary') as secondary")->from('tbl_activityFees2')->where($getDetails)->join('activity_name','activity_name.activity_name_id=tbl_activityFees2.activity_name_id','left')->group_by('m_id')->get()->result(); at your model.. if wont work then remove as field name from statement method .