# How to display the date comes from jQuery instated of display the current date?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

How to display the date comes from jQuery instated of display the current date?
I have a dropdown list and input with datepicker.

Now what I am doing is, When the user select year `2019-2020` from the dropdown then I am displaying the date in input field `31/03/2020`.

if choose `2020-2021` then it will display `31/03/2021` and so on.

I mean, Date and month are fixed only changing the year.

I am getting my output in the input field but when I click on the input field then it's showing the current date. I need whatever the date comes from the jquery that date auto selected.

```js
$("#year").change(function() {
  var dropdownDuration = this.value;
  var items = dropdownDuration.split('-');
  //alert("31/03/"+items[1]);
  $("#yearDate").val("31/03/" + items[1]);
});

$("#yearDate").datepicker();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
<select class="form-control" name="year" id="year">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Year</option>
  <option value="2019-2020">2019-2020 </option>
  <option value="2020-2021">2020-2021 </option>
  <option value="2021-2022">2021-2022 </option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="enddate" class="form-control datepicker" id="yearDate">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use datepicker paramaters like this:

`$("#yearDate").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',defaultDate:this.value});`

Try it as the below

```js
$("#year").change(function() {
  var dropdownDuration = this.value;
  var items = dropdownDuration.split('-');
  //alert("31/03/"+items[1]);
  $("#yearDate").val("31/03/" + items[1]);
});

$("#yearDate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    defaultDate: this.value
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
<select class="form-control" name="year" id="year">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Year</option>
  <option value="2019-2020">2019-2020 </option>
  <option value="2020-2021">2020-2021 </option>
  <option value="2021-2022">2021-2022 </option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="enddate" class="form-control datepicker" id="yearDate">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Give me some time to check.

Comment: It's working perfectly for me. Thanks for the help. upvote from my side.

Comment: I am happy to help you. We can keep the deeper and further relationship. Thanks

Comment: If you have a time then please check this issue  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54050168/not-getting-the-expected-output-from-the-model-query-what-query-should-i-use